# How can INSERT INTO database with out any ERROR?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have write this code for insert data to database, It will connect to database as well, but when i check the Result of INSERT to database it will give error,what is wrong there?

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost");        
define("USER", "admin"); 
define("PASSWORD", "Og%rA#b@d"); 
define("DATABASE", "database"); 

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
echo 'DataBase Connection Error';
exit();
}

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id, name, family) VALUES (2, 'a','b')");

if($result)
{
   echo "Success";
}
else
{
   echo "Error";
}

?>
```

Comment: What is error? can you post here as well

Comment: Is it just me or you're using `mysqli` and `mysql` functions? Those are 2 separated libraries as far as I know.

Comment: you are mixing  mysqli_* with deprecated mysql_*. try to do mysqli_query

Comment: echo your query and copy that and run that query from mysql...you will get what is wrong

Comment: This may help you - http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~hankley/d764/tut06/GopisettyPHP.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost");        
define("USER", "admin"); 
define("PASSWORD", "Og%rA#b@d"); 
define("DATABASE", "database"); 

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
echo 'DataBase Connection Error';
exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO table (id, name, family) VALUES (2, 'a','b')"); // use here mysqli_query and give connection object also in it before insert query

if($result)
{
   echo "Success";
}
else
{
   echo "Error";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks as if you're mixing mysqli_ and mysql_... 
Try changing `mysql_query("INSERT...")` to `mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO...")`

[W3 Schools Explanation for mysqli_query](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'table' (id, name, family) VALUES (2, 'a','b')");
```

table is [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your query on mysql console and check if it works.

Then as mentioned in the above posts you are trying to mix mysql and mysqli

try msyqli_query